# Using argv to get command line?

Tags: c, argv

Is there a way to set argv to something? Say, it's inputted the key stroke

```
t            6
```

or

```
t   6
```

And they execute the same thing given argv[0]=t and argv[1]=6. Neglecting white space.
Is this assigned or what is the functionality that allows argv to get input from the command line and use it in a program?

Comment: White space is typically ignored when passing arguments. That's why when things do have spaces the spaces are either replaced with `-` such as `my-arg` or done with `"` such as `"my arg"`.

Comment: The contents of `argv` are set by the process that calls the program.  When you enter a command at a shell, it's the shell that decides how to convert what you've typed into arguments, and it's the shell that handles whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

argv[0] = commandname. argv[1] = t, argv[2] = 6.

`argv` is the array of parameters, you can use parameters to do what you want.

For example :

```
ls -l
```

the argument list are : argv[0] = ls, argv[1] = -l, in this case the parameter specify an option to the ls command. You can do the same think with you program.

Answer (score 0):

White spaces are considered as separator for arguments in command line. If you want to include white space then put your argument withing quotes like "hello world". Here, both the words will go to argv[1] including the white space.